# prevent user with ID 1 edit

Tags: 7, users

I would like to prevent admin site (user id 2) to remove or change password user with id 1 although i need to admin add users and edit another users.
how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [User Protect](http://drupal.org/project/userprotect) module helped me.

Comment: If I have other role with permissions for edit users, the User Protect module prevent other role modify the user admin?  How can I configurate it the module?  I did a test with the other role and can modify the admin user.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Drupal no, no.  Leave root user alone. Just leave it.  If you are worry about security, change the username admin, to something else (admin is the most commonly use name hacker try to use).   Then just use uid 2 to administrate the site.

Comment: it doesnt solve my problem. beacuase  admin site check user list at first. site have 2 users. himself and main admin(with any idea). he edit my pass and login with my id. and now he is administrator. do u mean i delete record id 1?

Comment: ah I think I know what you are talking about now,  I'll submit another answer